# How to use indexers with Extension Methods having out parameter and function calls

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods, indexer

Is it possible to use `indexers` with `extension` methods.

eg. Consider it as an example only.

```
    public static object SelectedValue(this DataGridView dgv, string ColumnName)
    {            
        return dgv.SelectedRows[0].Cells[ColumnName].Value;
    }
```

**EDIT**

1. usage `mygrid.SelectedValue("mycol")`
2. How to use it as an indexer `mygrid.SelectedValue["mycol"]` rather than above one.
3. Is it possible to use it like this as well ? `mygrid.SelectedValue["mycol"](out somevalue);`

What are the syntax of getting this kind of values. Any simple example or link will work.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there are two issues here:

- C# doesn't (by and large) support named indexers<sup>1</sup>
- C# doesn't support extension properties, so you can't make `SelectedValue` a property returning something indexable instead

So no, the syntax you've specified there won't work. You *could* get this to work:

```
mygrid.SelectedValue()["mycol"]
```

but that's a bit ugly. I'd stick with the method form if I were you.

---

<sup>1</sup> C# 4 supports calling named indexers on COM objects.

Comment: @Jon: What kind of indexer i need to create here in that case. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx. I read this link to create indexer but how will it work within extension class. Is it possible to work out using this within static class as i need to create indexer also static

Comment: I too would prefer the method specified above in my ques until unless i have named indexer for which i have to start working on C# 4

Comment: Why only supporting named indexers on COM?

Comment: @Jon: How it is possible to use named indexers in 2K8 with datatables and datasets and many more. i.e. `(new DataTable).Rows[0]["mycol"]`. Doesn't .net opens this indexers to every one in previous versions itself

Comment: @Shantanu: That's using the `Rows` property, which returns a `DataRowCollection` which itself has an indexer. See my second bullet point - you can't create extension properties.

Comment: @simendsjo: I believe there was a desire to support it more widely, but the cost was seen to be greater than the value provided. The C# team only has limited resources.

Comment: @Jon: I read related article on msdn for C# 4. But still i would like to know named indexers are available to Collections in all previous version (<C#4) but are not exposed to programmers. Isn't it something strange that having some functionality defined long ago was not provided earlier or microsoft didn't recognised that

Comment: @Shantanu: Named indexers just aren't supported in C# - the idea is that it's generally better to write a property which returns an indexable collection. I'm not sure to what extent I agree with that, but that's the explanation usually given.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to clarify the usage and intentions of `Extension Method`.

Consider a `Extension Method`

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string source)
{
    return source == null || source == string.Empty;
}
```

Now you extend your `string` class with this `Extension Method`

```
var myString = "Hello World";
Assert.AreEqual(myString.IsNullOrEmpty(), false);
```

**This is what .NET does on compilation:**

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(string source)
{
    return source == null || source == string.Empty;
}
```

Using our old school

```
var myString = "Hello World";
Assert.AreEqual(IsNullOrEmpty(myString), false);
```

Extension method is nothing but a visualization to what we were used to do.

Well, extending indexers could be possible but Microsoft did not think about it.