# How to use ranges with List in C#?

Tags: c#

With C# 8 we got ranges to get "sub lists".

While this works:

```
var array = new string[] { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
var subArray = array[0..1]; // works
```

This does not:

```
var list = new List<string> { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
var subList = list[0..1]; // does not work
```

How can I use ranges with lists?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

List does not itself support Ranges. However, if all you have is a Range, you can create a helpful extension method like so:

```cs
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static List<T> GetRange<T>(this List<T> list, Range range)
    {
        var (start, length) = range.GetOffsetAndLength(list.Count);
        return list.GetRange(start, length);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it to get your sub-List:

```cs
var list = new List<string> { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
var subList = list.GetRange(0..1);
```

Comment: List doesn't support indices? Um? So according to you, `myList[1]` should fail with a compiler error?

Comment: Lists do support Index.

Comment: Lists support indexing with integers, but not with `System.Index` or `System.Range`.

Comment: @yaakov That's not correct. System.Index is (somehow) supported. With `Index idx = ^1; var x = new List<string>() { "abc", "def", "ghi" }[idx];` the value of `x` will be `"ghi"` (at least in .NET 5).

Comment: True, I forgot the compiler will try unwrap it for countable collections.

Answer (score 11):

Just for completeness, I know this isn't exactly what OP is asking for.

`List<T>` has a `GetRange`-Method.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.getrange?view=net-5.0

```
List<?> range = list.GetRange(0,5);
```

It doesn't have much to do with the new language feature but it does what it says.

Please do not use `ToArray` only to use that fancy new language feature. It's not worth the overhead.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ToArray()` method to solve the problem:

```
var list = new List<string> { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
var subList = list.ToArray()[0..1]; // works
```

But note that `List<T>` has `GetRange` method that does the same thing:

```
var list = new List<string> { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
var subList = list.GetRange(0,1);//abc
```

Comment: I was going to validate the post of this comment but you deleted your question, thus I put it here: I don't know if I understand the purpose but extension methods don't support indexed behavior and never will because what extension methods are: [C# extend indexer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67856682/cant-create-an-sqlconnection-in-c-sharp) and [How to use indexers with Extension Methods having out parameter and function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117351/how-to-use-indexers-with-extension-methods-having-out-parameter-and-function-cal)

Comment: Thanks Olivier Rogier the second one is very useful link

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi Most of the time, you say the best shortest answer! :)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you can't.  From the language specification:

> For example, the following .NET types support both indices and ranges: String, Span, and ReadOnlySpan. The List supports indices but doesn't support ranges.
>
> [Type Support for ranges and indices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/ranges-indexes#type-support-for-indices-and-ranges).

So the only way would be something like this, which is a bit clunky:

```cs
var subList = list.ToArray()[0..1];
```

Edit: I will leave the rest of my answer here for the record, but I think the answer using `Range` is more elegant, and will be significantly faster, especially for large slices.

### Benchmarking and Extension Method

The following demonstrates how much slower using `ToArray()` can be (using LINQPad - `F.Rnd.Str` is my own helper method for generating random strings):

```cs
var list = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    list.Add(F.Rnd.Str);
}

// Using ToArray()
var timer = new Stopwatch();
timer.Start();
var subList0 = list.ToArray()[42..142];
timer.Stop();
timer.ElapsedTicks.Dump("ToArray()");

// Using Indices
timer.Reset();
timer.Start();
var subList1 = new List<string>();
for (int i = 42; i < 142; i++)
{
    subList1.Add(list[i]);
}
timer.Stop();
timer.ElapsedTicks.Dump("Index");

// ToArray()
// 3136
// Index
// 28
```

Therefore an extension method like this will be very quick:

```cs
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static List<T> GetSlice<T>(this List<T> @this, int first, int last)
    {
        var slice = new List<T>();
        for (int i = first; i < last; i++)
        {
            slice.Add(@this[i]);
        }

        return slice;
    }
}
```

Then you can add this to the benchmark:

```cs
// Using Extension Method
timer.Reset();
timer.Start();
var subList2 = list.GetSlice(42, 142);
timer.Stop();
timer.ElapsedTicks.Dump("Extension");
```

Benchmark results:

```cs
// ToArray()
// 2021
// Index
// 16
// Extension
// 15
```

### Range

One of the answers uses `Range` to achieve the same thing, so for comparison:

```cs
timer.Reset();
timer.Start();
var range = new Range(42, 142);
var (start, length) = range.GetOffsetAndLength(list.Count);
var subList3 = list.GetRange(start, length);
timer.Stop();
timer.ElapsedTicks.Dump("Range");
```

Benchmark results:

```cs
// ToArray()
// 2056
// Index
// 21
// Extension
// 16
// Range
// 17
```

You can see the bottom three methods are essentially the same in terms of speed (as I run it multiple times they all vary between 15-21 ticks).

Comment: your `GetSLice`-Method is alot less efficient than `List<T>.GetRange`. While basically having the exact same functionality.

Comment: Actually it's pretty much identical in terms of run speed, I'll add it to my benchmark.

Comment: it would be if you intialized the new list with a meaningful capacity, and use Array.Copy like the original does. Your perfoamcnetest is not a really good test. Your extension is massively outperformed by the original.

Checkout https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,597

Using a Timer and only do one operation is not a good way to measure performance.

Comment: `ReadOnlySpan<string> subList = CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan(list)[0..1];`

Answer (score 3):

Rather than converting the `List<T>` by copying it to array you could [access the internals as a `Span<T>`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bygBT5).

This saves unnecessary allocation and copying.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<string> { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
        ReadOnlySpan<string> subList = CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan(list)[0..1];
        Console.WriteLine(subList.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(subList[0]);
    }
}
```